# Tkinter wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 5

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to find in the coordinate of mycar(x1) but it is error I tried to find the solution but I could not understand it. Can someone explain to me? Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        #create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=600, height=250)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.road()
        self.crossing()

    def road(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 50, 450, 50)
        self.canvas.create_line(50, 100, 450, 100)

    def crossing(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(350, 50, 350, 100)
        self.canvas.create_line(375, 50, 375, 100)


class Car:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, vx, vy, color, example):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
        self.color = color
        self.example = example

    def drawit(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, color):
        self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color)

    def moveit(self, vx, vy):
        self.example.canvas.move(vx, vy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_canvas = Example(root)
    my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    mycar = Car(60, 60, 125, 90, 3, 0, "red", my_canvas)
    mycar.drawit(60, 60, 125, 90, "red")
    mycar.moveit(3, 0)
    print (mycar.x1)
    root.mainloop ()
```

The error message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "D:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/untitled/2001.py", line 55, in <module>
     mycar.drawit(60, 60, 125, 90, "red")   File "D:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/untitled/2001.py", line 45, in drawit
     self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, color)   File "D:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
 line 2495, in create_rectangle
     return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)   File "D:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
 line 2474, in _create
     *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
 _tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_rectangle` takes 4 positional arguments (x1,y1,x2,y2) and then a set of key-value pair options.

You need something like:

```
self.example.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)
```

Comment: Apparently, I forgot to put the word "fill". Thanks

Comment: color is a string, e.g = fill="red"